# MySQL -  Как сделать много фото к одному товару?

Tags: mysql

Добрый день, всем! Хочу узнать такую вещь - в БД MySQL у меня есть таблица **products**, в котором есть поле **images**. Сейчас в поле images(VARCHAR) храниться просто название фото и расширение файла, например - *asus-s300-notebook-pc.png*.

Мне нужно сделать, чтобы у товара было не одно фото, а бесконечное множество, как это лучше реализовать? Как Вы решаете такую задачу?

Может лучше сделать поле images BLOB вместо VARCHAR и прямо в БД хранить все загруженные фотографии?

Comment: К чему такие извращения с blob. К тому же, если не ошибаюсь, в поле images blob будет храниться только одно изображения. Ошибаюсь?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Я бы сделал так: завёл таблицу `images (product_id int, path varchar)`, и выбирал бы картинки join'ом.

(Центральная идея правильного дизайна базы данных — одно логическое значение на ячейку.)

Comment: Пытаюсь добавить таблицу images, MySQL выдает ошибку - #3 - Error writing file '.\u251774856_im\images.frm' (Errcode: 28)

Comment: Разобрался - закончилось место на харде.